# I can't start my docker in win10

Tags: docker, windows-10

I start docker in Windows 10, what can I do now?
I tried to reboot my system and start docker too, the same problem occurs.

[image]

Comment: docker_engine miss

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should config hyper-v

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install